# Why TWO separate result file (.jtl) gets generated for 2 Slave machines?

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

I using distributed mode using 1 Master and 2 Slave machines. But when I execute test from Master, TWO separate result file (.jtl) gets generated for each of the Slaves.

How to resolve this issue, I want to have only one result file (.jtl)

Comment: Got resolved, it was generating 2 result files (.jtl) because the "jmeter-server.bat" was not started on Master machine.